# Extra space at the end of UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I added text in `UITextView` and to understand the boundaries I colored my `UITextView` with cyan color.

[image]

After google.com there is some extra space which I want to remove.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *desc = [self htmlAfterReplacingTagsAndAddingStyle];
        _descriptionTextView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [desc dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
        _descriptionTextView.linkTextAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] };
        _descriptionTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
        _descriptionTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [self setTextViewHeight];
    }
```

**setTextViewHeight**

```
- (void)setTextViewHeight {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:14.0];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _descriptionContainer.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.font = font;
    NSString *desc = [self htmlAfterReplacingTagsAndAddingStyle];
    label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [desc dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    [label sizeToFit];
    _descriptionTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor;
    [_descriptionTextView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -80, 0)];
    _descriptionContainerHeight.constant = label.frame.size.height;
    }
```

I read about setting content inset but that is not helpful. Changing the value of -80 doesn't have any impact.

I would appreciate some pointers which can help me remove the extra space present at the bottom of uitextView.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 [_descriptionTextView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

as can be readed in `UITextView` Class reference

> textContainerInset  Property The inset of the text container's layout
>   area within the text view's content area.
>
> Declaration
>
> OBJECTIVE-C
>   @property(nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets
>   textContainerInset
>
> Discussion
>
> This property provides text margins for
>   text laid out in the text view. By default the value of this property
>   is (8, 0, 8, 0).

Hope this helps

Comment: Agree.  I think the OP's method to measure string height is either incorrect, or at least wasteful.

Comment: Hi Reinier - Thanks for the answer. But it works in some cases, not all. If my string has no line breaks then it works like a charm. However, if my string has line breaks then still I face issue as posted above. I will upvote your answer but can't accept it as a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

To remove all padding:

```
[textView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0; // to remove left padding
```

If you want to remove Multiple new lines into single one,
In `textViewDidEndEditing:`

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\n+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *trimmedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@" "];
textView.text = trimmedString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get somewhere with textContainerInset (see @ReinierMelian answer).  There's also opportunity to vastly simplify the text height measurement...

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:14.0];
CGFloat width = _descriptionTextView.bounds.size.width;
NSString *string = [self htmlAfterReplacingTagsAndAddingStyle];
CGRect rect = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];

CGRect frame = _descriptionTextView.frame;
frame.size = CGSizeMake(width, rect.size.height);
_descriptionTextView.frame = frame;
// due to @ReinierMelian...
_descriptionTextView.extContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for an attempt to simply my answer. But your code doesn't take care of spaces and line breaks in the string. I need to preserve that in my case :)

Comment: @AsthaGupta - the code above handles any string input content exactly as the text metrics system does.  I've tested it to show that height changes exactly proportionately to the number of \n present in the string (* font height (+ leading, line spacing, etc) )