# UITextView leaving space on top

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Textview is leaving some space from the top edge. I tried both below way but nothing is working, it is still leaving some space.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

textView.textContainerInset = .zero
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
```

[image]

Comment: Please show me your screenshot here

Comment: @iOSTeam Please check edited post

Comment: textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false) ?

Comment: Yeah also tried with this

Comment: Are you using custom class for textview?

Comment: you have added the correct code, but please check in your project are you using any extensions for text view. try to add TextView in one demo project and check

Comment: @iOSTeam I checked I am not using any extension for textview

Comment: @VSP Is it possible to share full code of this app, if it is demo app ?

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951518/extra-space-at-the-end-of-uitextview

Comment: Can it be that you have scrolling enabled for your `UITextView`?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, the issue is due to a third party code 'Tabman' which is automatically adjusting Insets of its child view.